# <authorizationEntry queue="queue.>" read="test" write="test" admin="test" />

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

Hi earlier we were using below authorizationEntry to access(read/write) queues starting with `"queue."`.
Corresponding entry from activemq.xml

```
<authorizationEntry queue="queue.>"
 read="test" write="test" admin="test" />
```

As per the latest requirement from client(External system), is there a possibility to access queues starting with `"queue."`.without credentials(username/password)
please let us know what changes we have to make in activemq.xml or configuration to achieve the same i.e., access queues without credentials

These queues are used in routes created using apache-camel ,spring DSL language

Comment: take a look http://activemq.apache.org/security.html#Security-Anonymousaccess

Comment: To allow anonymous access to the broker, use anonymousAccessAllowed attribute and set it to true as shown above. Now, when the client connects without username and password provided, a default username (anonymous) and group (anonymous) will be assigned to its security context. You can use this username and password to authorize client's access to appropriate broker resources (see the next section). You can also change username and group that will be assigned to anonymous users by using anonymousUser and anonymousGroup attributes.

Comment: Thanks @ Hassen Bennour for quick response
As per your comment , we can add below line in activeMq.xml and users will be able to access queues without credentials _<simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="true"> <users> <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager" groups="users,admins"/> <authenticationUser username="user" password="password" groups="users"/> <authenticationUser username="guest" password="password" groups="guests"/> </users> </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>_ please confirm .please provide me a working example for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in doc :

> To allow anonymous access to the broker, use anonymousAccessAllowed
>   attribute and set it to true as shown above. Now, when the client
>   connects without username and password provided, a default username
>   (anonymous) and group (anonymous) will be assigned to its security
>   context. You can use this username and password to authorize client's
>   access to appropriate broker resources (see the next section). You can
>   also change username and group that will be assigned to anonymous
>   users by using anonymousUser and anonymousGroup attributes.
>    src http://activemq.apache.org/security.html#Security-Anonymousaccess

so i think this can do the stuff

```
<simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="true">
  <users>
    <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager" groups="users,admins" />
    <authenticationUser username="user" password="password" groups="users" />
    <authenticationUser username="guest" password="password" groups="guests" />
    <authenticationUser username="test" password="test" groups="test" />
  </users>
</simpleAuthenticationPlugin>


<authorizationEntry queue="queue.>" read="test,anonymous" write="test,anonymous" admin="test,anonymous" />
```

if you use Advisory you have to add authorized groups to create Advisory topics :

```
<authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="anonymous" write="anonymous" admin="anonymous"/>
```